# How to Remove Magento Folder name from URLs?

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect

I have a directory **store** in which magento files and folders reside. Therefore if I want to access the site, I need to specifically type the complete URL *www.example.com/store* to access.

I use avrixe hosting and have little idea about php stuff.

To counter the issue, I tried logging into cpanel and in website settings tried following
**Folder in hosting Space - \expamle.com\www\store** , This yielded 403 error. Please tell me how can this be achieved without fuss. Should I just chage the **Redirect to URL** in website settings to the complete URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 403 error might come from the redirection to `http://www.example.com/store` that Magento performs because this is the configured base URL. After you changed the directory from /www to /www/store, this URL does not work anymore and it shoul be `http://www.example.com/`

**Steps to fix it:**

1. change the cpanel settings back to the path without "store"
2. Go to Magento admin. `System > Configuration > Web` and remove "store/" from the base urls in the "Secure" and "Unsecure" sections.

   Do not remove the trailing slash, it should look like`http(s)://www.example.com/`
3. Now change the directory in cpanel to the path with "store" again

Comment: after changing the setting to without "store" getting for 403 for mysite/store/ and 404 for mysite/store/index.php....

Comment: yes, this step was necessary to be able to access your admin panel again at example.com **without /store**

Comment: right now i am not able to access anything. So it's not possible to do the second step

Comment: if your cpanel settings are correct, cleaning the Magento cache might help (delete contents of `store/var/cache`). Also, clear your browser cache because browsers cache redirections.

Comment: i am on aspnet hosting so had to do few extra things and now able to get the same working with the help of your method. thanks a ton